# Custom configuration for JBoss applications?

Tags: java, xml, jboss

I've built a simple alert monitor to display the health of various applications. This is configured by XML, as each monitor instance needs to show different metrics. An example configuration may be:

```
<machine>
  <monitors>
    <check type="connectivity" name="Production Server">
      <property key="host" value="ops01.corp" />
      <alarm />
    </check>
  </monitors>
</machine>
```

Currently, I'm storing this in the root of the C:\ drive of the server. What would be nice is if I could put it in the deploy directory of the JBoss server, and could somehow get a reference to it. Is this possible? I looked at MBeans but it didn't seem to support complex XML structures.

Robert

Comment: What sort of application is it? If it's a WAR deployed in JBoss, can't the config file go inside the WAR?

Answer (score 3):

Try JOPR - http://www.jboss.org/jopr .

For custom metrics, you can write your own plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

You can get an input stream for any file in the classpath by using the [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream(String name)`](http://www.ermalaev.spb.ru/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) method. Just pass the location of the file relative to the classpath.